# Android SDK platform

Tags: android, windows-7

I'm totally newbie to android development. Using Android SDK and AVD manager, I'm trying to install SDK Platform( android 3.2). But  getting following error :

File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-3.2_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)

Not sure, why this file in not installed when I installed android SDK.

Secondly whats more confusing why it is needed linux.zip file when I'm insalling in windows environment(windows 7).

Please help !

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that I need run eclipse as 'Administrator' to avoid this access denied error in the current version ADT (version 15).

Comment: sure, on Windows 7, if you want to install anything you should do so "as administrator". Some things prompt you automatically, but if they don't, right click run as Administrator should help.

Answer (score 1):

**if** you want to install SDK, use this [link](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r12-windows.zip) copy it to c then extract. then add location to eclipse from: window > preferences > Android  and choose location from SDK location

**if** you already have SDK and want to update go to SDK folder > tools> android.bat 
go to available package and install the nre API "remove check from Display updates only"